# Having trouble with the query formula for a report in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-query-language, google-sheets-formula, importrange

Here's the formula I have. Please evaluate and let me know if you see any issues.

`=(query(importrange("sheetLink","FormResponses"),"Select Col1, Col4, Col5 Where Col3 Contains '"&EmployeeName&"' And Col4 >= '"&ReportStartDate&"' And Col4 <= '"&ReportEndDate&"' And Col8 = '"&JobName&"'",-1))`

Any help you could give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the ampersands and provide a range in the sheet "FormResponses".

Comment: I think the query itself does look OK if EmployeeName etc. are named ranges

Comment: @JPV removing the &'s yields a #ERROR!

Comment: @Tom Sharpe  they are named ranges.  I'm getting a #N/A error, but the yield remains the same even with a wildcard.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet, so that we can see the actual data?

Comment: Assuming col4 contains dates, remove the single quotes around StartDate en EndDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual function that worked properly with the IMPORTRANGE function is as follows:

`(query(IMPORTRANGE("1qDKiRFFFnX5ORvleTIAoEcxD0WDjGopvA5UqcWVOfNs","FormResponses"),"Select Col1, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col10 Where Col3= '"&EmployeeName&"' and Col4>= Date '"&Text(DateValue(ReportStartDate),"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' and Col4<= Date '"&Text(DateValue(ReportEndDate),"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' Format Col4 'MM/DD/YY', Col7 '$#,##0.00'",-1))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this to make sure the dates work properly:

```
=query({A:H},"Select Col1, Col4, Col5 Where Col3 Contains '"&EmployeeName&"' And Col4 >= date '"&text(ReportStartDate,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' And Col4 <= date '"&text(ReportEndDate,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' And Col8 = '"&JobName&"'",1)
```

[image]